# Magento: How do I reset Configurable Attributes on a Configurable Product?

Tags: magento

When creating a configurable product there are options as to what is to be configurable, e.g. size, colour or size and colour (with a typical clothing product).

Some of my products have been setup as having both size and colour variants, however, I need them to be configurable by size only. I want just the size drop-down on the page, not two drop downs for size and colour.

How can I 'reset' the configurable products that are wrong to be as per just imported, i.e. so that I can choose what the size/colour options are? Is there some flag I can remove from these products in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by deleting entries in catalog_product_super_attribute that corresponded to the product_id for the product I needed to reset.

There after I was able to rebuild the products so that they had just a 'size' drop down instead of both 'size' and 'colour' (which was what I wanted).

To find which products I needed to 'look into' I ran this query:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT( product_id ) AS cnt
FROM catalog_product_super_attribute
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
ORDER BY product_id
```